# How to make this code compatible with IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works in all browsers except for older IE versions. It'll be accessed by users, some of whom are still using IE7. I'm not a coder and the author isn't available until next week so I'm at loss how to refactor it so that all browsers show only the options defined in `chk`.

```
    for (var x=1;x<5;x++){
      var st='select[name="Score_'+x+'e"] option';
      $(st).each(function(){
        var chk=',0,1,2,3,4,5,,,,,,--,';
        var sn=','+$.trim(this.innerHTML)+',';
        if (chk.indexOf(sn)==-1){$(this).hide();}
      });
      st='#tableScoringInfoBox'+x+' strong';
      $(st).html('1-10 Ratings explained');
    }
```

Comment: @Ibu: The values that are supposed to be hidden are showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix would be to simply replace `.hide()` with `.remove()`, though there's no way of knowing without seeing more code if that will impact something else.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. You can't really *hide* an `<option />`, can you?

Comment: You can in modern browsers (whether it's valid or not is another question), but IE7 didn't allow that.

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know. Oh the filthy things browsers let you do these days... :)

Comment: Thanks! That's quite the intricate detail to know.